# Loop through column and check if value in current row differs from value in previous row

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel-Table**

```
     |      A       |       B
-----|--------------|-----------------
1    |  Product_A   |   
2    |  Product_A   |
3    |  Product_A   |
4    |  Product_B   |       1
5    |  Product_C   |       1
6    |  Product_C   |
7    |  Product_D   |       1
8    |  Product_E   |       1
9    |  Product_E   |
10   |  Product_E   |       
11   |  Product_F   |       1
12   |              |
```

---

In the above Excel table I have a list of different products in `Column A`. 
A product can appear **multiple times**.

Now, I want to achieve that in `Column B` each time a product switches in `Column A` the number `1` is inserted. 
I have no clue how to achieve this with `VBA` but I think it must be something like this:

```
Sub Run_Loop()
If product_from_previous_row <> product_from_current_row THEN
Sheet1.Range("B:B").Value = 1
Else
End IF
Do Until Sheet1.Range("A:A").Value = ""
Loop
End Sub
```

Do you know what `VBA` I need to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA:

In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A1,"",1)
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you require VBA, then:

```
Sub FilB()
Dim N As Long
N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:B" & N).Formula = "=IF(A2=A1,"""",1)"
End Sub
```